# Redirection issue in Oauth2

Tags: keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

I'm developing simple microservices with Oauth2 with keycloak as authorization server.
Following is the code which returns list of albums when hitting the url: - http://localhost:8087/albums

```
@Controller
public class AlbumController {
    @Autowired
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oauthService;
    
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @GetMapping("/albums")
    public String getAlbums(Model model,@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser principal,Authentication auth) {
OidcIdToken token=principal.getIdToken();
String tokenValue=token.getTokenValue();
        Authentication authentication=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken=(OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client=oauthService.loadAuthorizedClient(oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), oauthToken.getName());
        String jwtAccessToken=client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
        String url="http://localhost:9091/albums";
        HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer "+jwtAccessToken);
        HttpEntity<List<AlbumsRest>> entity=new HttpEntity<List<AlbumsRest>>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<List<AlbumsRest>> responseEntity=restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<AlbumsRest>>() {
        });
        List<AlbumsRest> albums=responseEntity.getBody();
        model.addAttribute("Albums", albums);
        return "albums";
        
    }

}
```

Following is my application.properties file :-

```
server.port=8087
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mywebclient.client-id=tcs
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mywebclient.client-secret=2KcMN6xsmJH235k6TlLXUXj3iY3sAl8i
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mywebclient.scope=openid,profile,roles
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mywebclient.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mywebclient.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8087/login/oauth2/code/mywebclient

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mywebclient.authorization-uri=http://localhost:7070/auth/realms/developer/protocol/openid-connect/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mywebclient.token-uri=http://localhost:7070/auth/realms/developer/protocol/openid-connect/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mywebclient.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:7070/auth/realms/developer/protocol/openid-connect/certs
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mywebclient.user-info-uri=http://localhost:7070/auth/realms/developer/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mywebclient.user-name-attribute=Utkarsh0911
```

Whenever I'm hitting the url http://localhost:8087/albums, it performs too many redirections and finally end up on a page with message "This Page isn't working".

Answer (score 0):

this loop usually occurs when the redirect URL is not defined as permitted in the application. Please check here:
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-how-to-solve-oauth2-err-too-many-redir

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).